# Problems opening this file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run this file.js https://gist.github.com/johnchristopherjones/fb4e916d0b66584e71a3
with node on windows 10 but so far I'm getting

```
module.js:327
   throw err;
   ^
```

or

```
Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\server.js'
```

I gotta mention that I'm new to node and I'm trying to learn as much as I can, any good source of learning would be apreciated too.

Comment: What is `module.js`? Did you install all required modules needed by server.js?

Comment: `module.js` is the module loader in node.js. If it throws an error it most commonly is due to some dependencies not being installed, so you right - I guess the required modules have not been installed.

Comment: I dont really know, all I did was to download node.js from the official website and follow this tutuorial https://codepen.io/johnchristopherjones/post/setting-up-openid but no success...

Comment: So you ran the command `npm install express express-session connect-firebase passport-openid passport` listed in that tutorial?

Comment: I ran the commands, I don't know man..do I need a database or what?

Comment: Did you run the commands in the directory where your file is located?